# Exclusão de registro mestre-detalhe TCxGrid

Tags: delphi, devexpress, dataset

Bom dia, pessoal!

É o seguinte: eu configurei um grid (TcxGrid) para ter um mestre (cabeçalho) e um detalhe (itens) para exibir informações agrupadas conforme a minha necessidade. 
Porém esse grid fornece ao usuário a opção de excluir registros que foram inseridos no mesmo utilizando a tecla delete. 
Mas, ao tentar realizar a exclusão do item selecionado pelo usuário, o  `RecNo` do `TOraQuery` conectado ao detalhe não considera a posição atual do cursor, mas sempre a última.

Tentei alterar a propriedade `Deleting` em `OptionsData` para permitir o usuário deletar, mas a mesma não tem sucesso.

Há uma forma de resolver este problema ou existe uma solução de contorno?

Comment: Muito complicado, observei elo nome que os 2 componentes, Grid e Query são de terceiros? Independente de se sim, talvez a opção será desligar o mestre detalhe antes da exclusão!

Comment: Júnior, sim, são de terceiros. TcxGrid da DevExpress e o TOraQuery é da Devart. Mas de qualquer forma, eu já tentei com o TClienteDataSet, e mesmo assim não deu certo. 
Tentei há pouco realizar um loop na query para excluir o registro, mas sem sucesso.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontrei a solução:

Na propriedade `DataController` do `Grid Detalhe`, há uma opção chamada `KeyFieldNames`, ela deve ser relacionada ao campo "ID" que está sendo excluído.

Testei e deu 100% certo.